# Magento 1.9 stuck after step 4 i.e shipping option

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.9 version and onepage checkout stuck at shipping method's section i.e. option 4.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: When someone was trying to place an order online then onepage checkout process was stuck at step 4 that is select shipping method. 

Please check screenshot for example - https://prnt.sc/lgqw6n

So, I looked online and found following solution and it worked for me.

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time on search and trying multiple solutions, the following one was the right solution to my problem.

You have to update payment.phtml file in the base or your custom theme

```
/app/design/frontend/[base]/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Add **id="checkout-payment-method-load"** to the fieldset

Code snippet before edit

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
</form>
```

Code snippet after adding the id (solution)

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load" >
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
</form>
```

This should solve the problem. Please leave a comment if it helped you too. Thanks.